# Assign directly to the request body when POST-ing

Tags: json, serialization, alamofire

I would like to assign some JSON text to the request body of a POST request and not have any variables. So, instead of this as the request body, for example...

```
myVal={"hello"="world"}
```

I would like this...

```
{"hello"="world"}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a custom parameter encoding...

```
import Alamofire

struct JsonParameterEncoding: ParameterEncoding {

    private let jsonString: String

    init(jsonString: String) {

        self.jsonString = jsonString
    }

    func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {

        var urlRequest = urlRequest.urlRequest!

        if urlRequest.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") == nil {

            urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        }

        urlRequest.httpBody = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)

        return urlRequest
    }
}
```